# Exclude concrete java package from restart classloader in spring-boot-devtools

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

**Problem:** I have a complex application, currently running on Spring Boot. Start time is about 60 seconds, so I would like to use Spring Boot Devtools to reduce restart time, but with default settings it give me almost the same 60 seconds. Excluding modules doesn't help much, even with the only 2 or 3 modules with which I'm working most, "hot" classloader restarts about 40 seconds. I think this is connected with heavy database and caches initialization logic, which is very hard to move to separate module.

**Question:** Is it possible to exclude dedicated package from restart classloader?

I would like to do something like:

```
restart.exclude.config=/modules/mainmodule/target/classes/com/company/app/configs/
```

but it doesn't work, because Spring Boot Devtools only checks full 'classes' folder, in this case `/modules/mainmodule/target/classes/`

Comment: I would disable the cache if you can. For debugging when I trace through a query, I don't care if it's slow and needs to contact DB. So then you don't need to pay cost of loading cache at startup.